# Retrieve value from sql database

Tags: java, android, sql, string, adapter

Im trying to retrieve the value from the database file for a string, here is the on create method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mImage= (NotesDbAdapter.KEY_IMAGE);
    Log.v("IMAGE PATH====>>>> ",mImage);}
```

However log is showing the value retrieved is the default value, i.e image and it is not setting mImage to the value in the database.

This is the imagepath stored in the **KEY_IMAGE** db:

> /storage/emulated/0/Download/Black-Wallpapers-Desktop-Windows-7.jpg

This is the log file:

> 08-04 16:16:13.355: E/BitmapFactory(26933): Unable to decode stream:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /image: open failed: ENOENT (No such
>   file or directory)

**UPDATE**

```
private void populateFields() {
    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        mTitleText.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
        mBodyText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
        mColor =(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_COLOR)));
        mDate =(DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE ));
        mImage =(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_IMAGE)));

    }
}
```

The other fields work fine but the mImage doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a query and retrieve data from that.